# Is it possible to record the things happening on an iPhone/iPad screen without Jailbreaking?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, screen-capture

I would like to record the video of things happening in an iPhone/iPad screen. Here there is a change from usual applications available, that records device screen(view inside) from an application. I need to record things from the home screen of the device even the application(which records) is in background. Is it possible to implement?.

Also I wish to save this captured video to the iPad. (inside the application sandbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even if you will find a way to do Apple will reject this app.

Comment: Is it possible by jailbreaking the device?

Comment: @cherukkayi I think it will be. But I've never done anything that is anyhow related to jailbreaking, so I can't promise it.